# yo angular generates files in wrong path ( home directory )

Tags: yeoman, ubuntu-14.04, yeoman-generator-angular

yo angular generates the files in my home directory and I don't know why.

I did the following:

ppa for node

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup | sudo bash -
```

then install node

```
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

create a symlink

```
sudo ln -s "$(which nodejs)" /usr/bin/node
```

install yeoman

```
sudo npm install -g yo
sudo npm install -g generator-angular
```

next steps from the instruction from https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular

```
mkdir my-new-project && cd $_
```

now I run

```
yo angular test1
```

now all the files will be created in my home directory instead of the my-new-project directory where I am currently. What did I wrong?

node -v: v0.10.36

npm -v: 2.5.1

Update1: new npm version

**Solution:**

yo angular looks for .yo-rc.json file in the current directory, if the file isnt there it tries to find it in the home dir. To solve this:

look for a hidden .yo-rc.json file in the home directory and delete it.
Or create an empty .yo-rc.json file in the directory you want to use.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Thanks to issue page at https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular/issues/1037#issuecomment-83118093 the solutions was relatively easy.

After the command `mkdir my-new-project && cd $_`
I needed to create an empty `.yo-rc.json` file with `{}` as content to this folder.

Then I could start yo and all files are created in my my-new-project folder now.

Answer (score 21):

In case anyone else stumbles on this. The reason will be that a .yo-rc.json file is in the "wrong" directory.

Delete it and all will be well.

Answer (score 6):

This started happening to me after I ran `yo` from my home folder by mistake. Apparently I didn't clean up the generated files properly and left the ~/.yo-rc.json around. All you need to do is get rid of the .yo-rc.json in your home folder and run `yo` from your desired folder again.

Answer (score 3):

Probably you have there .yo-rc.json file. You should delete all hidden files in home directory which yeoman created and it's should works.

Answer (score 1):

you should try not to install node with sudo, that causes your troubles.
Take one instruction out of this link to install your node for usual user
[Instructions](https://gist.github.com/isaacs/579814) and it should work.

Comment: Thanks, but my answer seems to be the right way for solving that problem.

Answer (score 0):

I searched for .yo-rc.json file in the folder it wrongfully creates your project in, then showed all hidden files via "defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles YES" in terminal then reload Finder ( alt button + right click on finder icon) and deleted the hidden .yo-rc.json file and other hidden files that came with it. Then reloaded finder again after using the same command as above but replace YES by NO.
That did it for me !