# How to get the current path of the running Yeoman generator

Tags: node.js, path, generator, yeoman, yeoman-generator

I have my own Yeoman generator.
I created a sub-generator to create a new *view* folder.

Basically, the usage is:

- open a new terminal
- cd into the parent folder
- run the yeoman command `yo my-generator:view`
- follow the instructions

This *view* sub-generator prompt a folder name.

**For example:**

If I want to create the view **authentication** on the default *views* directory.

```
cd views
yo my-generator:view
```

The result should be:

```
views //- Already created by the main generator
├── authentication
│   ├── authentication.controller.js
│   ├── authentication.template.html
```

Now, if I want to create a sub-view **login** for the authentication view.

```
cd views/authentication
yo my-generator:view
```

The result should be:

```
views //- Already created by the main generator
├── authentication
│   ├── authentication.controller.js
│   ├── authentication.template.html
│   ├── login
│   │   ├── login.controller.js
│   │   ├── login.template.html
```

Instead, the current (wrong) result is:

```
views //- Already created by the main generator
├── authentication
│   ├── authentication.controller.js
│   ├── authentication.template.html
├── login
│   ├── login.controller.js
│   ├── login.template.html
```

My struggle here is that I don't know how to get the current path when I run the command.

Actually, I just create the new folder with a default prefix path which is *app/views/*.
This is why **Authentication example** works.

However when my current path is deeper in the *views* folder, it will add the new folder at the root of the *views* folder.
If I could get the current path (of the cmd), I should be able to add this path as the prefix instead of setting a default and not static one.
This is why **Login example** doesn't works.

**Some code example:**

- `$that` is the current generator object
- `$that.viewNameCamel` is the name of the folder set by the user

I use a .txt file as template and then create the controller.js file.

```
const filePrefix = 'app/views/' + $that.viewNameCamel + '/' + $that.viewNameCamel + '.';

const exampleData = {
   controllerAlias: 'vm',
   otherVar: 'example'
};

$that.fs.copyTpl(
   $that.templatePath('controller.txt'), 
   filePrefix + 'controller.js', 
   exampleData
);
```

**Tried:**

- $that.env.cwd
- process.cwd()
- __dirname
- path.js library

**Similar:**

- [Issue 1037](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular/issues/1037)
- [Question 28481715](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28481715/yo-angular-generates-files-in-wrong-path-home-directory)

So guys, do you have a clue on how do I get the current folder path ?
Is there an alternative solution here ?

Thanks !

**EDIT 1:**

---

The problem here is the `.yo-rc.json` present on the root directory of the projet.
The file rewrite the path so I should delete it to fix the problem.
However if I delete this file, the user configuration will no longer be saved.
And I need it for later sub-generator usage.

Is there another way to save the user configuration ?
Or once again, is there another way to get the current real path ?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is kinda old but for any one who comes later, 
from the documentation https://yeoman.io/authoring/file-system.html

`If you want to know from where the user is running yo, then you can get the path with this.contextRoot. This is the raw path where yo was invoked from; before we determine the project root with .yo-rc.json.`

from my experience removing the `.yo-rc.json` would mean that you need to manually check if the path provided is ok, having a fixed root point is something helpful.

Comment: Thank you! I missed this in the docs. This is the correct answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `.yo-rc.json` file from your root directory. This is the file that is responsible for locating your root irrespective of where you are in the file system.

I am not sure about the repercussions of removing it but nothing seem to have happened to the generators I built.

Now you can use `process.cwd()` and it will get the correct working directory.

For your use case to have a prefix `app/views`, you probably need to write some Javascript to append or not append the prefix based on where you are, which should be trivial.

Comment: Thanks for the answer nevertheless I need to keep this file alive. The data in it are from another generator and I need them for the view generator (like app name, current language, author, ...). I should be able to access these data at any time (eventually, I could save these data in a new custom file, I will try some stuff).

Comment: Hmm, if you are willing to create a `.yo-rc.json` with empty config in every directory then you can achieve this but that would be an ugly directory structure. Or may be there is a way to create the file, recognise the working directory and then delete the file? Too far fetched but worth a try I guess.

Comment: If simply I could simple delete the `.yo-rc.json` file to get the real path, I will find the solution to have the correct path, no worry about it. Then, I must change all the referances to `x.config.set(...)` and `x.config.get(...)` to avoid creating and using the file. The alternative is could be to use https://www.npmjs.com/package/edit-json-file which is pretty likewise. Then I will have my own file and the stuff will be pretty much the same. Even if this solution sounds possible to me, that seems a little bit overkill to just work around the path finding.

Comment: **Test 1 :** you are right, removing the `.yo-rc.json` just fix the wrong path (with $that.env.cwd and process.cwd()).

Comment: **Test 2 :** removing `'app/views/' + ` from the filePrefix plus the **Test 1** stuff make sub-generator *view* works like charm. The final step is now to replace the whole native config by my own.

Comment: **Test 3 :** `edit-json-file` actually edit the files in the npm generator package... I can't access the actual generated project folder or I just don't know how but I just read the full yo doc and nothing...

Comment: Well, why not add a different json file like `config.json` and parse it for config information, only downside is you won't be able to use the Yeoman API for config but that is a fair compromise I think.

Comment: I don't want to throw away the `.yo-rc.json` file because it helps me to work with the root path for some other sub-generators. And I don't want to find a "none yo solution" like recreating my own storage, my own module to find appropriate path, etc...

Comment: Hmm, then let’s go into yeoman source code to find a possible loophole. Will give it a try later this week. Or you can try posting a new issue in their Github repository.